# Payum - How to repeat Paypal payment when user close browser being on paypal side.

Tags: symfony, payum

I have an ExpressCheckout up and running. Now I want to give the user the chance to make the payment at a later time. For example he closes the paypal process I keep data saved.

I guess this must be pretty straightforward but somehow it wont redirect me to paypal anymore. The only thing I did so far is to use the identifier to find an existing model instead of creating a new one. This part works so it'll find the specific record of the PaypalExpressPaymentDetails table. But as I said it wont redirect to paypal. Here is the code:

```
$paymentName = 'demo_paypal';
    $storage = $this->get('payum')->getStorageForClass(
        'Demo\UserBundle\Entity\PaypalExpressPaymentDetails',
        $paymentName
    );

    /** @var $paymentDetails PaymentDetails */
    $paymentDetails = $storage->createModel();
    $paymentDetails->setPaymentrequestCurrencycode(0, $currency);
    $paymentDetails->setPaymentrequestAmt(0, $amount);
    $storage->updateModel($paymentDetails);


    $captureToken = $this->getTokenFactory()->createCaptureToken(
        $paymentName,
        $paymentDetails,
        'payments_transaction_success'
    );

    $paymentDetails->setReturnurl($captureToken->getTargetUrl());
    $paymentDetails->setCancelurl($captureToken->getTargetUrl());
    $paymentDetails->setInvnum($paymentDetails->getId());
    $storage->updateModel($paymentDetails);
```

Executed Controller:

```
...
$identificator = new Identificator($entity->getId(), 'Demo\UserBundle\Entity\PaypalExpressPaymentDetails');
$captureToken = $this->payLateByPaypal($entity->getAmount(), "USD", $entity->getId(), $identificator);
return $this->redirect($captureToken->getTargetUrl());
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I likely answer this question but before I want to clarify somethings?

When you say "For example he closes the paypal process I keep data saved." you mean the user close a browser or click paypal cancel button and come back to your site?

Could you post what your model contains before you try pay again and  after?

BTW: payments_transaction_success - is not the right name, all failed\pending\success payments redirected to that url. You have to check status there

Comment: Exactly, when he closes the window or something.
The model contains only like: id, token, correlationid, paymentaction (sale), return/cancel url. The rest is an empty json.

Thanks for the tipp. I do status checking in this controller but seems like a better idea to do so right here.

Comment: does he close the window after he logged in on paypal or before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reproduce it in the sandbox. Unfortunately it is a known issue. If the user logged in and access the page second time the payment [considered as canceled](https://github.com/Payum/Payum/blob/master/src/Payum/Paypal/ExpressCheckout/Nvp/Action/PaymentDetailsStatusAction.php). That's done this way to avoid endless redirection between your site and paypal one. I dont see an easy way to solve it.

**UPDATE**

In version 1.0 the cancel issue is handled correctly.

Comment: Ah I see the point now with: PaymentActionNotInitiated. Thank you for the detailed investigation!

I think this is good to handle. Either delete the current (no initiated) payment and create a new one at the point when a user wants to pay afterwards. Or keep data and create an additional one on payment. (The second one would mean that I'd have to deal with many-to-one in my specific case. I prefer the way with delete and create and go along with one-to-one).